# Is is possible to intercept Guest VM traffic on the host machine's Burpsuite

Tags: penetration-test, virtualization, kali-linux, burp-suite, tls-intercept

I'm running Kali on Windows 7 via VMWare, and would like to be able to access private network websites, which i can't seem to be able to do. So I tried to forward the system traffic to the host machine and on the host machine, configured burp to listen to a specific port on all interfaces, but that didn't work. So I have two questions:

1. How to intercept guest machine's traffic on host machine
2. Any other way to visit host machine's private network websites on the guest machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a security question. It depends of how to configure your vm networking. Is a bridged machine? is a NAT vm? is host-only?

- Host-only: you can't access to the host network from the vm... as name says, you can reach only the host, and not its network.
- Bridged: If vm is bridged it will be another "independent" machine on your network, so you already are on the same network as your host machine is.
- NAT: You can access to your host's network through host.

I guess you have a DHCP in your host's network, so setting vm as bridged is the easiest solution I think because you must do "nothing". If you have DHCP on your host's network, your vm is going to get an automatic IP and that's all. You can reach the same as your host machine. So you can set up Burp on your Kali vm and configure your browser (inside Kali vm too) to use the Burp's proxy (usually http://127.0.0.1 on port 8080 by default). Don't forget to install Burp's certificate to reach https pages. To do this is easy, enter with your browser (inside Kali vm too) to the page http://127.0.0.1:8080 , download the certificate and import it to your browser as truted authority, as simple as that.

Not sure what you are doing wrong, is not complicated. Can't help more without more data.

Good luck.

Comment: I actually missed on the fact that I was connected to the private network via VPN from home. At the office however, it works exactly the way you've explained. Is there a way to access private network on the guest machine when the host machine is connected to the private network via VPN?

Comment: Oscar already explained, If you NAT it, it will be inside the NAT network of your host, behind the VPN, if you bridge it, it will be treated as another computer in the same networks as the HOST (inside the VPN) but it has to be configured too. Select the NIC setting of the GUEST that best suites you.

Comment: Bro opposite. I want to intercept my request from vm to my host machine(ubuntu where burp is installed). How to perform this action?